# I made a multiple choice question in python and one part does not work

Tags: python

I made a multiple-choice question that allows a user to get a total of 3 hints(one hint per question) if he wants it. So, I created if/elif/else statement inside the hint section but when I run the code and I type "h", it just says I got the question wrong instead of providing a hint. Here is my code:

```
# POINTS
score = 0

# HINTS
hint = 0

#QUESTIONS
while True: 
  for t in trivia:

    answer = input(t["question"] + "\n\nAnswer: ").upper()

    if answer == t["answeris"]:
        print("Excellent!\n")
        score = score + 10
    elif answer == "h":
        hint += 1
        if hint > 3:
          print("Sorry! You used all the hints.\n")
          userhint1 = input("Answer: ")
          if userhint1 == t["answeris"]:
            print("Excellent!\n")
            score = score + 10
          else: 
            print("Oops! You got it wrong. The answer is " + t["answeris"] + ".")
            
        userhint2 = input(t['hint'] + "there is " + {3 - hint} + "hint(s) left. * \n" + "\nAnswer: ").upper()
        if userhint2 == t["answeris"]:
          print("Excellent!\n")
          score = score + 10
        else: 
          print("Oops! You got it wrong. The answer is " + t["answeris"] + ".")

    else:
        print("Oops! You got it wrong. The answer is " + t["answeris"] + ".")
```

Can someone tell me what I have done wrong?

Comment: What is the value of ```trivia```? Could you provide us example input and output?

Comment: I tried your code. It fails even when the correct answer is provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You input string is converted `.upper()` but your elif is lower, try this;

```
elif answer == "H":
```

Comment: You're welcome. You may also want to apply `.upper()` to `if answer == t["answeris"]:`, just in case the data is lower case.

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much!